# Have multiple category queries from the URL been fixed yet?

Tags: categories, tags, urls

Is it now possible to query multiple categories from the URL?

http://www.mywpsite.com/?cat=1+7

?

I think this has worked for [tags for some time](http://wpguy.com/articles/multiple-tag-category-queries/). If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a feature request for WordPress, the best way to get it addressed is to add a ticket on Trac.  Then developers can adopt the task, patch WordPress, and submit the improvements to the next version.  If a [Trac](http://trac.wordpress.org) ticket has already been created for a particular feature, you can comment on it to weigh in and follow the subsequent discussion.

The last time I checked, there was a ticket for querying multiple terms in a taxonomy (tags, categories, or custom) at the same time: [Ticket #12891](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12891).

According to the ticket, the project is scheduled to be included in WP 3.1.  But we won't know for sure until the first release candidate comes out.  According to the [last scope update before the feature freeze](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/process-and-scope-for-3-1-part-i/), this *is* going to be included in 3.1 ... but it won't be "fixed" until 3.1 is actually released.

If you want to use the feature now, you have a couple of options:

1. You can download the actual patches from Trac and patch your WordPress installation to add the new functionality.  I wouldn't recommend this because they may or may not depend on other 3.1 improvements that aren't included explicitly in these patches (i.e. improvements added by other tickets).
2. Install the [WordPress Beta Tester](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/) plug-in and upgrade to version 3.1-alpha.  This would be the *safest* way to use the new feature, **but still might cause problems!**  WordPress 3.1 isn't considered "stable" yet and some of the features/code might (will definitely) change before the final release date.  There's no guarantee that the latest nightly build will be bug-free.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify multiple **category ID's separated by commas**, they will be combined in `category__in` (or `category__not_in` if the ID is negative). `category__in` means the post must be in *at least one* of the specified categories (an **OR** query). `category__not_in` means the post must not be in one of the specified categories. The relevant code can be found in [`wp-includes/query.php`, lines 1871 to 1909](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/query.php#L1878).

For **tags** you always have to work with **slugs**. If you separate them with **commas**, they end up in `tag_slug__in`, if you do it with **plus signs** they go into `tag_slug__and`. This means if you want an **OR** query you combine them with comma's, if you want an **AND** query you do it with plus signs. Here the relevant code starts at [line 1946](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/query.php#L1946).

Comment: My example uses the plus sign for categories. That's what I'm interested in here.

Comment: @trnsfrmr: My mistake, I looked over it. But you still got your answer: no, it is not supported at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use scribu's excellent Query Multiple Taxonomies plugin and get the functionality you want today...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/

Comment: That's actually a bit different.  This plug-in will let you query single terms from multiple taxonomies simultaneously (`?genre=jazz&artist=chet-baker` from the example).  It won't let you query multiple terms from a single taxonomy simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, it does (have you tried it?) - I'm using it right now for this exact purpose. The example you mention isn't the only thing it can do...

http://scribu.net/wordpress/query-multiple-taxonomies/qmt-1-1.html